# ENV variables only available in production console, not in app -- Rails, Figaro Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, environment-variables

I am using the figaro gem and have created an `application.yml` file with all of my variables as per the documentation. This application.yml file is located in a shared folder (I'm using capistrano) and is symlinked to config/application.yml within the current live app directory, however I can only access the variables in the rails console and not the app. My credentials are listed as follows (real details omitted):

Note: I have tried removing the "" speech marks and also prefixing this list with production: with each line having 2 spaces, not tabbed, and it doesn't solve anything. The permissions on the file are exactly the same, 777, as the databse.yml file which was implemented in the same way.

application.yml

```
FFMPEG_LOCATION: "/path/to/ffmpeg"
EMAIL_USERNAME: "me@gmail.com"
EMAIL_PASSWORD: "password"
S3_BUCKET: "my_bucket"
AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID: "my_secret_key"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "my_access_key"
```

I can access these variables in the production console =>

```
Loading production environment (Rails 3.2.14)
irb(main):001:0> ENV["S3_BUCKET"]
=> "my-s3-bucket-name"
```

However they don't return anything in the app itself. I set my linux box up following Ryan's excellent Pro railscast episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps

How can I get these variables accessible in the app itself?

If anyone needs more code just shout.

**EDIT**
I removed the figaro gem implemented the yaml config shown in the following railscasts tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-revised. I think this is effectively what the figaro gem was doing however instead of using ENV variables, the tutorial uses CONFIG[:variables] which seem to work great.

Comment: passenger phusion or unicorn?

Comment: Im using nginx, unicorn, postgres

Comment: I'd go with straight yml instead of environment variables for your s3 secrets, but if you really want to do it the env way:  For nginx, you have to set env vars in the main context of your config file.  The reason for the trouble you're having is that nginx runs as its own user, when you log in and run the console you're a different user.

Comment: Put this as an answer and I'll gladly accept. I changed to a yml config which I've added to my question but I had no idea why they variables wouldnt show. Your explanation makes a lot of sense thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Comment:

Nginx runs as its own user, so the environment variables need to live in it's space.  As a user when you log in and run console, you're accessing a different set of environment variables than the nginx user accesses.

You can do this if you choose by adding them to the nginx config in the `main` context.  But it's probably easier to go with straight yaml and add your secret tokens to your yaml file.

Comment: I know it's almost 3 years too late, but could you please elaborate how to make the variables "live in it's space" ? I've got exact the same issue - rails c production gives me Figaro.env.secret_key_base as valid value, but ENV["secret_key_base"] inside config/secrets.yml does not recognize it. I receive `Missing secret_key_base for production environment, set this value in config/secrets.yml>`